# .NET Configuration file encryption

Tags: .net, security, encryption, configuration

We currently have a mechanism to encrypt our configuration file on a configuration section basis. The tool that we use for encryption is aspnet_regiis.exe.

The downside to this approach is that we consistently need to keep track of which configuration section to encrypt which is error prone and manual intensive.

Is there a way to encrypt the entire configuration file instead?

Thanks